# Redshift COPY command not working with octal delimiter

Tags: copy, amazon-redshift, delimiter, octal

I'm having an issue with using an octal value for the delimiter, I'm not sure if I'm missing something since I'm following what the Redshift documentation and other stack overflow post suggest.

Test csv file: octal_delimiter_test_file.csv

```
id\001name\001load_dttm
3\001Name 03\0012020-06-19 12:03:00.000
4\001Name 04\0012020-06-19 12:04:00.000
```

Redshift table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE octal_delimiter_test_table (
id int,
name varchar(20),
load_dttm timestamp);
```

COPY command:

```
COPY octal_delimiter_test_table
FROM 's3://myBucket/octal_delimiter_test_file.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'myCredentials'
CSV
IGNOREHEADER 1
DELIMITER '\\001';
```

Error message:

```
Invalid operation: COPY delimiter must be a single character;
```

If I try with

```
DELIMITER '\001';
```

I get

```
Invalid operation: Load into table 'octal_delimiter_test_table' failed. Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.;

raw value: 3\\001Name 03\\0012020-06-19 12:03:00.000

Err reason: Delimiter not found
```

I've tried using different delimiter values (1 to 43) but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what is in the source CSV file  - is the character used as a delimiter really ascii-001 (SOH) or 4 characters \,0,0,1?  You description and the Redshift error leads me to think that you really don't have ascii-001 in your file.